# Find the frequent elements from a list in pandas column grouped by another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, counter

My dataframe looks like given below

```
col1      col2
type1     ['A','C','B','D']
type1     ['C','A','F','E']
type1     ['F','E','G','H']
type2     ['A','E','F','G']
type2     ['A','E','J','K']
```

I have to find out the elements from the list in col2 that are frequently appearing to a given user input.
For example, if the user input is A. Then we have to find the top 3 elements that appear with A. And this has to be calculated for each value in col1.
i.e

```
type1 - most frequent element for A - A,C will be the output
type2 - most frequent element for A - A,E will be the output
```

The data posted here is sample data.

Comment: This could be better achieved using python ``dict`` rather than pandas.

Comment: Why cant it be done in Pandas? Any specific reason?

Comment: Nothing specific.

Comment: for type 1, you have F,A,C,E appearing twice.

Comment: @sammywemmy I guess he meant that items should be neighbours of A.

Comment: @Sid Please clarify what you  mean by `top 3 elements that appear with A. `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

def most_freq(series, input_):
    cnt = Counter()
    for row in series:
        if input_ in row:
            for i in row:
                cnt[i] += 1
    return [k for (k,v) in cnt.most_common(2)]

query = 'A'
df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2': lambda x: most_freq(x, query)})
```

Outputs:

```
        col2
col1    
type1   [A, C]
type2   [A, E]
```

Explanation:

One possible way to solve this question is to use a customised [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) function.

It uses a `Counter` to collect all counts of elements in each row which groups by `col1` if `user input` appears, and return its top 2 occurrences. OP can change the arg `2` in `cnt.most_common(2)` to `3` if you are looking for top 3 occurrences.

Comment: This works perfectly. For me, It is easy to understand and so easy to maintain. And I can easily modify it if needed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No worries man. Have fun coding!

Comment: Can you update the answer to handle the query as a list instead of a single string? I hope I am not asking for too much. Thanks

Comment: I changed the code to handle a list. Thanks.

Comment: @Sid I think this can be easily done by change the condition `if input_ in row:` to `if all(query in row for query in input_):`

Comment: No worries, you are fast!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216366/discussion-between-sid-and-zwjjoy).

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your question right - you want top 3 items that are neighbors of A:

```
from collections import Counter

def fn(x):
    c = Counter()
    for row in x:
        s = pd.Series(row)
        m = s == 'A'
        c.update(s[m.shift(fill_value=False) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)])
    return c.most_common(3)

print( df.groupby('col1').col2.apply(fn) )
```

Prints:

```
col1
type1    [(C, 2), (F, 1)]
type2            [(E, 2)]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

`C` is 2 times neighbor of `A`, `F` only once in `type1`

`E` is 2 times neighbor of `A`, in `type2`

---

If you want most common, you can do in `fn()`:

```
return list(dict(c.most_common(1)).keys())
```

This prints:

```
col1
type1    [C]
type2    [E]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(_list):
    a = _list
    b = [a.count(i) for i in a ]
    c = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':a,
                      'Count':b})
    d = c[c['Count'] == c['Count'].max()]
    e = d['Letter'].unique()
    f = np.array(e,dtype = object)
    return f

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['type1','type1','type1','type2','type2'],
               'col2':[['A','C','B','D'],['C','A','F','E'],['F','E','G','H'],['A','E','F','G'],['A','E','J','K']]
              })

df = df.groupby('col1').sum()

df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: func(x))

df
```